# React Metronic theme project running error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i have a React Theme in Metronic project running error.
after npm install
i start npm start .
build found this error.

> ./node_modules/socicon/css/socicon.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/socicon/css/socicon.css)
> Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Fm Tech\Downloads\demo1\demo1\node_modules\colorette'

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/75301849/4650866

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with node-sass, but the re-installing didn't help, So if you still have the problem. I would recommend installing earlier node version, personally I installed 12.smth and it fixed the error. Just remember to delete node_modules folder from the project folder and run npm install.

Answer (score -1):

Ohhh really easy

Just execute  this commond

```
yarn insall
```

not `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

first node-sass uninstall
then install again node-sass

```
npm install node-sass
```

most of time your node-sass install globally so uninstall globally